# OutOfMemory Java heap space when running on maven even though the memory has been increased

Tags: java, maven, out-of-memory

I am writing some JUnit tests which retrieve 200,000 records from MySQL. When I try to run the tests via eclipse, it went out of memory.

I have increased the heap space via the VM arguments to `-Xmx8G` and it solved the problem. However, when I try to run this on maven by calling mvn test, it is still saying it is out of memory even though I have added it to the pom.xml

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.22.2</version>
<configuration>
    <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
    <forkCount>2</forkCount>                        
    <argLine>-Xmx10000m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError </argLine>
</configuration>
```

```
[INFO] Running ABCTechRecords.TestCountUniqueRecord
Nov 03, 2019 6:46:44 PM 
ABCTechRecords.TestCountUniqueRecord init
INFO:  Starting test TestA 
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 585.821 s <<< FAILURE! - in ABCTechRecords.TestCountUniqueRecord 
[ERROR] 
TestA(ABCTechRecords.TestCountUniqueRecord )  Time elapsed: 585.801 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at ABCTechRecords.TestCountUniqueRecord.init(TestA.java:28)
```

Comment: Capture some debug logging of this test in isolation with `mvn -X test -Dtest=TestCountUniqueRecord` and paste any _relevant_ parts here (there is far too much logging to dump the whole thing I'm sure!).

Comment: An aside of the heap sizing, but does your test really need to load and retain 200,000 records? Can you not page/stream them and count on-the-fly etc. e.g. if checking uniqueness, add only the PK to a Set and fail if `pkSet.add(PK)` returns `false`

Comment: I am not sure which logging is relevant. I am loading and retaining the 200,000 records because it is also used in other tests. The tests did run successfully via eclipse but I don't understand why it wouldn't work on maven

Comment: Loading 200,000 records doesn't sound like proper testing at all.

Comment: You have configured two forked JVMs with 10000m each. You likely have Eclipse running somewhere too and your normal desktop apps (browser, mail etc). Do you actually have enough free RAM for a setting like that? Try testing by reducing forkCount and/or setting `-Xms8G -Xmx8G`. That way it will fail on startup if memory is too limited

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following configuration into the pom.xml file.

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>-Xmx4096m</argLine>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```